# Connect Bose QC 35 II with microphone

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, headphones

I have ubuntu 18.04 running on lenovo P53s(5.3.0-59-generic).

I have Bose QC 35 II headset paired using bluetooth. The audio is working good, but I am facing a problem when trying to use them as input device.

I have two profiles listed for audio output: `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)` and `Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)`. The former has much better audio quality.

If I go to Sound Settings my headphones are listed as input device (I have two options - `Internal Microphone - Built-in Audio` and `Bluetooth input - Bose`, the former is selected). However selecting the headphones as input device automatically changes the profile of audio output to `Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)`.  This profile results into significantly worse quality of the audio and also I hear the message `Call from` from time to time. If I try to change the audio profile back the input device also changes back.

I would like to be able to use the microphone and at the same time use `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)` audio profile. Is this possible?

Comment: Is the TLDR that I can't have both good audio and mic on? I think that is what the accepted answer suggests

Comment: Yep. Unless you're on Chrome OS or Android, HFP codec support on Linux isn't that great. And A2DP doesn't support mics at all. Keep an eye on https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/776 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1838151